# Why don't the Comments field display in the Admin Notification Template?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am using freeform 4.0.12 on EE 2.6.1. Everything works except the comments textarea field contents are not displaying in the Admin Notification.

Here is the form:

```
{exp:freeform:form 
form_id="1"
form:id="contact"
required="name|email" 
return="contact/thank-you" 
notify_admin="yes"
notify_admin_template="contact" 
}

<label for="first_name"><span>First Name:</span>
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" />
</label>

<label for="last_name"><span>Last Name:</span>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
</label>

<label for="email"><span>Email:</span>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
</label>

<label for="phone"><span>Phone:</span>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" />
</label>

<label for="comments"><span>Comments:</span>
<textarea name="textarea" name="comments" id="comments" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</label>  

<label for="captcha"><span>Enter this value:</span><br />
{freeform:captcha} </label><br />
<label for="captcha-2"><span>Here:</span>
<input class="captcha" type="text" name="captcha" value="" />
</label>


<input checked="submit_button" type="image" src="/photos/btn_submit.png" alt="submit form" />
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Here is the code in the notification form:

```
{first_name} {last_name} submitted the following information from the website contact page:

{all_form_fields}
    {field_label}
    {field_data}
{/all_form_fields}
```

When I get the response back it looks like this:

> Mark Twain submitted the following information from the website
>   contact page:
>
> First Name  Mark
>
> Last Name   Twain
>
> Email   markt@macx.com
>
> Phone   919-000-0000
>
> Comments

Note: The comments are blank. So sad.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<textarea>` as shown has *TWO* `name=` parameters.  I doubt that's helping matters.

Comment: Hi Scott. This is a classic example of what two sets of eyes are so valuable. Thanks.

Comment: heh, no kidding ...  I'm so glad that worked out. happy Friday!